# How to restore the default repositories in 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

My repositories are screwed. I need a fresh copy because my old one has a lot of problems. I've already tried http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ but I don't know what to select and the list it generated doesn't allow me to upgrade. So please give me the original repositories so that I can replace this one. I am from India.

Comment: have you check this one? http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Precise#Edit_the_repository_sources_list

Comment: @florian i did see that before i asked the question.thats how i found out about the website mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm dumping my `/etc/apt/śources.list`. It only contains repositories that come with Ubuntu. Some of them are deactivated in the default configuration but I don't know which ones. Anyway this list shouldn't give you problems. You should also empty the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` where all ppas you have added are saved.

So here comes the list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Beta amd64 (20120328)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Beta amd64 (20120328)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Beta amd64 (20120328)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```