# Package dependency problem preventing installing any program due to libvte9 dependency

Tags: 12.04, installation, dependencies

That is the error I get whenever I try to install wine, chromium, flash player or any thing else any help would be appreciated (a new Ubuntu user)

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
enigma: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
        Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2-1) but 7.22.0-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
        Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
        Depends: enigma-data (= 1.10~~pre-alpha+r2210-1.1) but 1.10~~pre-alpha+r2210-1.1 is to be installed
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit

I have tried `sudo apt-get install -f` here is the result of this:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information...
Done The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-3.2.0-29 linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae Use 'apt-get autoremove' to 
remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any help you can give me?

"Edit"
when i tried to install synapetic packet manager from the terminal i got this error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 synaptic : Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not installable
            Depends: libvte9 (>= 1:0.24.0) but it is not installable
            Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not installable" 
after that i tried the software center it gave me the same error as every other application

any other ideas

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I would start by restoring your repositories see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/191669/how-to-restore-the-default-repositories-in-12-04 and then do some research if Chrome will even run on 12.04

Answer (score 0):

use synaptic package manager, it will resolve its dependencies automatically or software center, if it doesn't work then install the libraries shown in error message using synaptic package manager.(Just type the library name and select the package and then click apply.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to do `sudo apt-get update` before install.