# Ubuntu doesn't show any updates anymore

Tags: apt, updates

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in April, but since I have barely received any system updates (the ones popping up automatically with the `Software Updater`).
When checking the kernel version with `uname -r` I get `4.4.0-21-generic` which according to this list [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) seems pretty out of date.

By trying to run an update manually with `apt upgrade` and `apt update` I receive:

```
sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  hostapd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ftp.lysator.liu.se/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                    
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                      
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                          
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Reading package lists... Done                                                 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
hostapd/xenial 1:2.4-0ubuntu6 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.0-3ubuntu2.1]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

Are there really any updates to install or is my system not finding them anymore?

Comment: Open _Software & Updates_ and change the settings to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a serious problem.  The only official update server on your system seems to be the `archive.canonical.com`.  All other servers listed above have been placed there manually after the inital system installation.

The missing update server's name should be `<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com` (for example **us.archive.ubuntu.com**) and it's not there.

You can try reconstructing `/etc/apt/sources.list` by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586595/restore-default-apt-repositories-in-sources-list-from-command-line) for example or you can re-install your system.  There are several other places all over the internet where you can find similar instructions on how to reconstruct `sources.list`.

Comment: Thanks this seem to have worked, I received an update list of 300+MB!

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  You're welcome!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Repositories not configured

Your Ubuntu repositories are not configured correctly.

1. Add some repository executing the command below:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted"
   ```
2. Now, try updating:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Upgrade:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I Was looking for this and here is the solution.

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

I'm on POP Os.