# Incompatibilities installing drivers for GeForce GT 750M on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I would like to install the drivers for the NVIDIA chip and I would like to install CUDA so I can program this chip.

Here's the description of my laptop:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Eduardo-Alienware-14 3.13.0-111-generic #158-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 16:12:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Details of my graphic chip:

```
$ sudo lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] [10de:0fe4] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05a9]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b2000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
```

According to http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/114708/en-us:

```
Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver 
Version:    375.39
Release Date:   2017.2.14
Operating System:   Linux 64-bit
Language:   English (US)
File Size:  73.68 MB
```

Driver version 375.39 is the driver I should use. I supports the following cards:

```
GeForce 700M Series (Notebooks):
GeForce GTX 780M, GeForce GTX 770M, GeForce GTX 765M, GeForce GTX 760M, GeForce GT 755M, [b]GeForce GT 750M[/b], GeForce GT 745M, GeForce GT 740M, GeForce GT 735M, GeForce GT 730M, GeForce GT 720M, GeForce GT 710M, GeForce 720M, GeForce 710M, GeForce 705M
```

Following [this tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/): I will not download the installer from the website. Instead I will use PPA.

Since, according to the tutorial, the xorg-edgers PPA provides the very latest NVIDIA drivers, I have ran the following commands to set it up:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpikxws_oj/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpikxws_oj/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 8844C542 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpikxws_oj/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 8844C542: public key "Launchpad PPA for xorg crack pushers" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease [65.9 kB]      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages [90.8 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [13.5 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages [88.6 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages [13.5 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en [28.4 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en [10.8 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe armhf Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe armhf Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main armhf Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe armhf Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main armhf Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe armhf Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe armhf Packages                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Fetched 312 kB in 9s (32.1 kB/s)                                               
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**First problem**: Why would some of the URLs already included in my sources file yield these errors?

**Second problem**: On the Additional Drivers section at the Software and Updates tab (when running sudo software-properties-gtk), the additional drivers should now be listed and are not... why? Would this be related with the first problem?

At this point, I believe I should see the drivers listed, before attempting an alternative approach to install the drivers:

```
# Install 375 driver
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

Any help on solving the two listed problems?

**Update on the first problem**:

Running:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

Showed that the armhf architecture was included as a foreign architecture. I have removed it via:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```

After doing so, I have removed the original sources.list file, and replaced with one that looks like this (let `<codename> = trusty`):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu <codename> main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu <codename>-security main multiverse universe restricted
```

(Which was kindly shared here: https://askubuntu.com/a/586601/273254). Doing this, fixed the problem of failing repositories. My output from updating is clean now:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
ejspeiro@Eduardo-Alienware-14:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: 1. Wrong architecture - `armhf` - for your hardware (how exactly it ended up there if for **you** to find out). 2. No, they shouldn't, because that tutorial is outdated and that PPA no longer carries Nvidia proprietary drivers (opening its webpage should have been enough to understand that). It'll try to elaborate an answer later.

Comment: On a second thought no, I will not. Better to install from scratch. From your other questions is clear you don't know what you're doing and the result is mistakes pilling on top of other mistakes. So, installing from scratch is the faster and better option. Then you can use this PPA for graphics drivers: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa . Then you can install CUDA (good luck with that).