# sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx error ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, lubuntu

hii i try to setup lets encrypt i follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) (this is done by digital ocesn)

i tri this command

```
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

i get this out put

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-31-23-194: Resource temporarily unavailable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-certbot-nginx : Depends: python3-certbot-nginx but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and i get this error tooo

```
  python-certbot-nginx : Depends: python3-certbot-nginx but it is not going to be installed
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

i check this location  `'/etc/apt/sources.list'`its have empty

> note:i update 16.04-->1804 update use  do release command

Comment: try `sudo chmod +x /etc/apt/sources.list` and update/upgrade again sir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore default apt repositories in sources.list from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586595/restore-default-apt-repositories-in-sources-list-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already have python 2.7 that why its happen :) then i install python 3.0 and try its will install