# Kvm Installation missing dependencies 18.10

Tags: dependencies, kvm-virtualization, 18.10

I am trying to install KVM/Qemu using the guide on the [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation).
But i am getting error due to unmet dependencies for qemu-system-x86.
Is there a work around or should i file a bug.

```
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bridge-utils is already the newest version (1.5-16ubuntu1).
bridge-utils set to manually installed.
libvirt-clients is already the newest version (4.6.0-2ubuntu3).
libvirt-daemon-system is already the newest version (4.6.0-2ubuntu3).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qemu-kvm : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:2.12+dfsg-3ubuntu8.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit: Here is the sources.list as requested by the comments below

```
$ grep -v '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic restricted main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates restricted main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports restricted universe multiverse main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security restricted main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu cosmic stable
```

Comment: 'Impossible Situation' usually means you have an unwise set of sources. Those unwise sources introduce conflicts. Check your sources. If you don't know how, then edit your question to include the complete contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: Also, did you install any software via a ppa? And, have you deactivated any ppa without ensuring that the corresponding packages are downgraded to correspond to your distro's default versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore default apt repositories in sources.list from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586595/restore-default-apt-repositories-in-sources-list-from-command-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: For this case in particular, atm the missed qemu version is only in the security pocket - so the above hints about completing the source.list again and ensuring all pockets are met seem correct to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)