# Missing the package libidn11, can't figure out how to repair or reinstall it

Tags: apt, package-management

I've been running into a lot of problems on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation with a package named libidn11. Not having a functioning version of it gets in the way of installing other packages or upgrading installations such as my installation of R. How would I go about fixing this problem without choosing the nuclear option (fresh reinstallation of Ubuntu)?

`E: The package libidn11 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Simply trying to reinstall in [as such](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/libidn11) doesn't work, and I get the same error message shown above.

EDIT: See @steeldriver's comment

```
arta@lappy-486:~$ apt policy libidn11
libidn11:
  Installed: 1.33-2.1ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 1.33-2.1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.33-2.1ubuntu1.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.33-2.1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

EDIT 2: Here is the output of `sudo apt update`:

```
arta@lappy-486:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for arta: 
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                                                 
Get:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]                                                 
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                      
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-team/hydrogen/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]                                                 
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-team/hydrogen/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.4 kB]
Hit:8 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease       
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
Get:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,103 B]
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Oracle Java (JDK) 8 / 9 Installer PPA' to 'Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED)'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-team/hydrogen/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What does `apt policy libidn11` return? was your installation of R from a PPA?

Comment: @steeldriver see the edit i made in my post. I don't know re: the second part of your comment.

Comment: How about `sudo apt install --reinstall libidn11`

Comment: @CharlesGreen Same thing.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @user535733 done

Comment: Looks like you have deleted the Ubuntu repositories from your apt sources. You must [restore the default apt repositories in sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586595/restore-default-apt-repositories-in-sources-list-from-command-line)

Comment: Doesn't work, I get a `permission denied` message, and also I already have `sources.list` with the line in there, but thanks anyway.