# Can't install libidn11 on my ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I have installed a soft and then try to check enviroment.
which i find is that :

```
libidn.so.11 => not found
```

so i want to install libidn but which is failure:

```
simon@simon-parallels:~/Downloads/ITHSData/bin64$ apt policy libidn11
N: Unable to locate package libidn11

simon@simon-parallels:~/Downloads/ITHSData/bin64$ sudo apt-get install libidn11:1386
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libidn11:1386
```

So is there any way to install this libidn11?

ps: I have referenced [Missing the package libidn11, can't figure out how to repair or reinstall it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147143/missing-the-package-libidn11-cant-figure-out-how-to-repair-or-reinstall-it), but sadness it did not work.

Comment: You really need to [edit] your question to show what you actually did to install this package. There was no solution provided in the linked Q&A and it was closed quoting two other solutions. What did YOU try?

Comment: `libidn11` was removed from the Ubuntu repositories after 20.04. However, `libidn` is in the Ubuntu repositories for all supported releases.

Answer (score 3):

Install libidn11 from Ubuntu 20.04 in Ubuntu 22.04 by running the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11_1.33-2.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libidn11_1.33-2.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install libidn12 on Ubuntu 22:04

Ref: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn/+question/703040