# How do I override a missing dependency?

Tags: apt, dependencies

I installed a package using `dpkg --force-depends -i` because it requires [`libidn11`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1147143/80483) which is no longer provided.

I then created a symlink from `libidn.so.11` to `libidn.so.12` (auto-installed) and the package now works just fine.

However, I no longer can update the system using `apt full-upgrade` because I get

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 icaclient : Depends: libidn11 but it is not installable
...
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Alas, `apt --fix-broken install` just removes `icaclient` which is not an option.

So, is there a way to tell `apt` to ignore all problems with a specific package and pretend that all its dependencies are met?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a cheat, but here is what I did and `apt upgrade` no longer complains:

1. Open `icaclient.deb` in Emacs. Get an archive buffer:

```
M    Mode       Size       Date&time       Filename
- ----------  --------  ----------------  ----------------
  -rw-r--r--         4  2020-04-16 08:18  debian-binary
  -rw-r--r--     53421  1969-12-31 19:00  control.tar.gz
  -rw-r--r--  72952536  2020-04-16 08:20  data.tar.xz
- ----------  --------  ----------------  ----------------
              73005961                     3 files
```

2. Open `control.tar.gz` (hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on it), get a `tar` buffer:

```
 drwxr-xr-x    root/root          0 ./
 -rw-r--r--    root/root      54528 ./md5sums
 -rw-r--r--    root/root        921 ./control
 -rwxr-xr-x    root/root        160 ./postrm
 -rwxr-xr-x    root/root        918 ./preinst
 -rw-r--r--    root/root        879 ./conffiles
 -rwxr-xr-x    root/root      70411 ./prerm
 -rwxr-xr-x    root/root      70579 ./postinst
```

3. Open `control` (again, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on it), edit the text file, replacing `libidn11` with `libidn12`.
4. Save `control` (hit <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>).
5. Save `control.tar.gz` (switch to it and hit <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>).
6. As root, `apt --fix-broken install` and accept removal of `icaclient`.
7. As root, `dpkg -i icaclient.deb` - no warnings, not errors!
8. As root, `cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu; ln -s libidn.so.12 libidn.so.11`.

I am sure there is a way to do it without Emacs, but I am also quite sure it will be way more keystrokes.