# Broken packages after updating source list to use Xenial instead of Artful

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I changed my default Ubuntu source list to change the dist name to be `xenial` instead of `artful` since support is gone.

I ran:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And it updated with success all (except rabbitmq/nvidia/wireless-regdb) my packages.

My issue  is that now a lot of my packages are broken and I can't install without fixing the issues.

Error below:

```
❆ ~/ ➭ sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.5) but 1.10.22-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libdbus-glib-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2 (= 0.106-1) but 0.108-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
❆ ~/ ➭ sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python3-pil.imagetk : Depends: python3-pil (= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) but 4.1.1-3build2 is to be installed
                       Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried

```
$ sudo apt-get clear cache
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall <broken package>
$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

Without success.

Do I need to `apt-get purge <broken package>`? It saying it will remove a lot of vital packages and it scares me a bit when trying to do so on python3 for example

Comment: That was a bad idea. You can't downgrade the system this way. You can only break it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore default apt repositories in sources.list from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586595/restore-default-apt-repositories-in-sources-list-from-command-line) and [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install new a supported release Ubuntu 19.10 after you have backed up your data. That is my opinion