# Unbuntu 22.04 nvidia drivers not istalled

Tags: drivers, nvidia

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 ,My nvidia driver not recognized
I try to install them with drivers-devices and it give me `error 404 could not fetch`.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it is "not recognized"? How are you trying to install "with drivers-devices"? What is the GPU? Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: I tried drivers-devices and also ubunto-driver autoinstall and even the nvidia-515 driver but I get coult not fetch... but I install vlc without any problem..in my additional-drivers I I can't mark any driver and thr oroblem is that I want my second monitor to work ?? It work at the instalarion of ubuntu but in my display setting I can't turn two screen even the other screen is recognized...in minnows it work just fine

Comment: Try and use answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586595/restore-default-apt-repositories-in-sources-list-from-command-line) to restore your sources.list. Seems like you're aiming at resources that are no longer available (a wrong mirror, etc)

Comment: Thank you...I will try I new to linux so it all seems a bit hard maby some steps to beginner guide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in two steps..
1.i change the server from Israel local server to ... ubunto server
2.sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-dkms-515
And that all ...thank you all